# How to make ansible-playbook fail if become user or password was wrong?

Tags: ansible

When ansible-playbook fails to `become`, the process will `Escalation succeeded` message.

IMO, this behavior is not kind because not looks like fail.

Are there any configuration not to hang if `become` failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `ignore_errors: yes`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html